# Reference a method (with argument) in the Rocket Pants collection response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, ruby-on-rails-4, rocketpants

Using the Rocket Pants gem for an API, I'm wanting to be able to return a custom value in the `collection` json. For example, I'm currently doing this:

```
collection(
  current_user.prizes,
  include: { location: { only: [:title] } },
  only: [:last_prize_at]
)
```

This returns a JSON response like the following:

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "location": {
        "title": "My name"
      },
      "last_prize_at": "10-10-15"
    }
  ],
  "count": 1
}
```

This is pretty straight-forward and is working as it should.

**What I'm wanting to do is** reference a method with an argument in the response, for example:

```
# current_user has a method called "prizes_from(location_id)"
collection(
  current_user.prizes,
  include: { location: { only: [:title] } },
  only: [:last_prize_at],
  prize_list: current_user.prizes_from(:location_id)   # < this line doesn't work
)
```

The code above obviously does not work, however, it shows what I'm trying to do. Here is an example response of what it should look like:

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "location": {
        "title": "My name"
      },
      "last_prize_at": "10-10-15",
      "prize_list": [                # < here
        { .... }
      ]           
    }
  ],
  "count": 1
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `methods` option was what I was looking for:

```
collection(
  current_user.prizes,
  include: { location: { only: [:title] } },
  only: [:last_prize_at],
  methods: [:user_prize_list]        # Added line here
)
```

Unfortunately, I've not found a way to be able to access sub-methods directly, or how to use arguments. So to make the code above functional, I had to add this to my `Location` model:

```
def user_prize_list(location=nil, user=nil)
  location ||= self
  user ||= location.user
  user.prizes_from(location.id)
end
```

It works though!